# ffmpeg setting chapters by framecount instead of milliseconds?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I've just gone through a process of adding chapters to a file using ffmpeg. Works great but, the way I found to do it required converting the marker placements to milliseconds from the original timecode. Since my editing software will display my files with framecounts, it occurred to me that it might be possible to save some conversion effort by telling ffmpeg where to place the chapter markers using these framecounts.

Here's an example of a chapter marker I placed:

```
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=7000
END=291199
title=Chapter marker
```

I see that the TIMEBASE is set to 1/1000. That means that the START time for this chapter is 7 seconds (210 frames). To what extent will ffmpeg accept a formula as its TIMEBASE? Can I put in something like:

```
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/30
START=210
END=8736
title=Chapter marker
```

or

```
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=100/2997
START=210
END=8736
title=Chapter marker
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

With the lack of response, I tested. Both of the formula posted worked, one for 30fps content, the other for 29.97fps content.

Thanks.

Comment: and long answer? :D

Comment: https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/407124-ffmpeg-setting-chapters-by-framecount-instead-of-milliseconds Amended my script per jagabo's post in that thread. in essence, for 29.97fps, use 1001/30000 instead of 100/2997 as it would be more accurate.